# Is 'icons' a good tag?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to [icons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icons).

On the (currently) 10 questions with that tag...

- 1 is about emoji in Gmail subject lines
- 2 are about emoticons in Facebook
- 3 are about icons in Trello
- 1 is a request for an icon generator
- 1 is about icons in Yahoo! Mail
- 1 is a request for an icon search service (closed)
- 1 is a request for sources of icons

This really seems to be a "meta-tag" to me. It can't be the only tag on the question, and it means different things to different people. I *really* doubt anyone is going to follow that tag so that they can answer questions in it. What's an "icon" expert, anyway?

(For reference: [Stack Overflow Blog: The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/))

Comment: Getting the feeling that more and more the tags should just be the names of web apps and nothing else

Comment: There are some non-web-app tags that definitely make sense, like [tag:security] and [tag:privacy].

Comment: yeah, [tag:icons] should be wiped..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [icons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icons) tag has been removed from all of those questions. The clean-up tool will remove it within the next 24 hours.